# Two self invoking anonymous functions defined causing error

Tags: javascript, gulp

I've two self invoking functions but I'm getting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

**code:**

```
(function(){  //a.min.js
    console.log('main')
})()

(function(){ //b.min.js
    console.log('two')
})()
```

Thanks guys for the solution but I wonder how this can be fixed if concatenation and minification is done through some automation tools like gulp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the semicolons

```
(function(){
    console.log('main')
})();

(function(){
    console.log('two')
})();
```

which makes the first IIFE interpreted as not closed, and the second block of code creates an error as it's interpreted as an argument for the first IIFE.

Comment: why semicolons, they are on separate lines, and then I'll have another problem, I'm using gulp for minification, I can't force semicolons there

Comment: You're going to have to, as that's the only way to fix it. The issue is the missing semicolons

Comment: @user3610227: Line breaks don't separate statements. Only semicolons do. Here is a simplified version of your example, using function references: `(foo)()(bar)()`.

Comment: got it, but suppose first IIFE is in a.min.js, and the second is in b.min.js, both get minified by gulp,

Comment: semicolons shouldn't be an issue for minification, even if javascript has automatic insertion of semicolons, it should never be wrong to just add them where they are supposed to be.

Comment: @user3610227: You can automatically insert a semicolon at the end of each source text. Or use something like https://github.com/yyx990803/semi.

Comment: I added semicolons to a.min.js and b.min.js at the end, and the automatition tool works fine too so that solved the problem

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that this is interpreted as

```
(expression)(args to call function with)(args to call function)(args to call function)
```

And what you really wanted was

```
(expression)(args to call function with)(expression)(args to call function)
```

The only way to do that is to interrupt the expectation with a semicolon

```
(expression)(args to call function with);(expression)(args to call function)
```

Alternatively, you could use the less standard `!`

```
!function(){
 console.log('main')
}()

!function(){
 console.log('two')
}()
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to fix this without semicolons would be to wrap each IIFE in a block:

```
{(function(){
    console.log('main')
})()}

{(function(){
    console.log('two')
})()}
```

Or, perhaps more simply, to just combine the two:

```
(function(){
    console.log('main')
    console.log('two')
})()
```

One last option would be to put all your IIFEs into an array and then call them sequentially:

```
[
    function(){
        console.log('main')
    },

    function(){
        console.log('two')
    }
].forEach(function (fn) { fn() })
```

This last one may be good if you need a lot of these, but again, it's probably best to combine if possible.